# Чтения файла построчно

Tags: java

Написал в пятницу работало сегодня не работает что я не так делаю ?

```
String line = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Николай\\Documents\\TestSMS\\GSM.txt")).get(3);
```

Получаю

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Николай\Documents\TestSMS\test.txt
```

Comment: NoSuchFileException - нет такого файла. Проверьте наличие указанного файла.

Comment: Да я проверил файл на месте.

Comment: В приведённом коде указан файл `GSM.txt`, а в исключении говорится о `test.txt`.

Comment: Суть  не меняет путь верный файл на месте.

Answer (score 2):

Вам Java прямым текстом пишет, что не может получить доступ к какому-то файлу (наверняка его просто нет).

Проверяйте пути к файлам перед тем, как работать с ними.

```
File f = new File(filePathString);
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
    // Если файл есть, работаем с ним.
} else {
   // Если файла нет.
}
```

Также могут быть проблемы с открытием файлов, если нет прав доступа на на него.

Comment: Спасибо решил переносом файла в другую папку.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решина переносом файла

String line2 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\Users\Николай\Desktop\TestRider.txt")).get(13);